# How do I send an image via Bluetooth from my Mac to my iPhone?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, bluetooth

I need to connect my Mac to my iPhone and send a picture via Bluetooth. Can someone give me step by step instructions as in how to do this ?

note: if there's any other way i could do this, then please share it with me

Comment: People: keep in mind that the OP's looking for *Bluetooth* file transfer, not Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth transfer is only available to jailbreakers. If you want to go that route, [AirBlue Sharing](http://www.if0rce.com/en/airblue-sharing-2/) claims to be able to send/receive files over Bluetooth.

Non-jailbreak options include the $1.99 app [Photosync](http://www.photosync-app.com/photosync/en/features.html), which uses Wifi and requires a free desktop app to receive/transfer files to it:

> PhotoSync will transform your photo handling forever. It‘s the first
>   app that makes wireless transfer of your photos/videos from or to your
>   computer and other i-Devices - a breeze.
>
> Supported transfer
>   directions: Device to Computer (Wi-Fi), Computer to Device (Wi-Fi),
>   Device to Device (Wi-Fi & Bluetooth)

Or you could use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/), drop a picture in the Dropbox folder on your desktop then use the iOS client to access the picture and save it to the device if you want.

Comment: Why this simple operation is blocked by Apple?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send picture from iPhone to a computer via bluetooth unless the iPhone is jailbroken. You can however use [iCloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html) (via wifi) or [iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4236) (wifi or USB).  Or you can email it to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your devices set up and paired, Bluetooth turned on on both, (I keep Bluetooth off on my phone most of the time) click on the Bluetooth symbol at the top of your Macbook, pull down to "send file" and choose the file. You'll need to "accept" on your phone.

From a real rookie

Answer (score -1):

Just get Dropbox for both your iPhone and your PC. It's free and easy to use.

Comment: Not Bluetooth, technically...